# Alternative to using Passenger for rails on FreeBSD9.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, freebsd

I want to use Ruby on Rails via rbenv with Apache2.4 on FreeBSD9.1, running ruby-2.0.0p247 and rails 3.2.13.

My problem is that rails needs a hook into apache, which would normally be accomplished using passenger. However, due to a bug in the OS, passenger won't work. Linkage below detailing the specific OS bug. I'd like to get things moving well before FreeBSD9.2 arrives (9.2 resolves the issue).

Is there an alternative to passenger? How can I accomplish my goal in the least exotic way possible?

`url`[passenger on github commit: check for broken freebsd version](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/e3612124fd4708a6a3df76c8fe27319789e14214)
`url`[Catching C++ std::bad_cast doesn't work in FreeBSD 9.1](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-toolchain/2013-January/000692.html)
`url`[Why does catching std::bad_cast not work on FreeBSD 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413703/why-does-catching-stdbad-cast-not-work-on-freebsd-9)

Conveniently, and even after much initial research, after posting this question, another [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options?rq=1) was discovered. While quite comprehensive, I'm not sure it entirely answers my original question. Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I work at Phusion.

You can use any of the other app servers described at [Ruby on Rails Server options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options?rq=1). Unicorn, Puma, Thin... they will all get the job done, though not necessarily as easy as Phusion Passenger.

But if you prefer Phusion Passenger then there's still hope. A pull request came in a couple of days ago which works around the FreeBSD bug: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/pull/87
I haven't got time yet to review the pull request (I'm too busy doing my yearly taxes) but perhaps you can try it out yourself. Installation instructions for the git repo are documented in the readme.

Comment: That's pretty fresh code, considering the bug is 6 months old. If you have time this week[end] to look it over, that would be awesome and appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't think I'll have time soon, right now I'm super focused on getting my tax administration done before the government deadline, so I can only answer to Enterprise customers' priority support requests in a timely manner. Please feel free to test the pull request yourself.